# JIRA custom "order by" on text field

Tags: jira, case-when, jql

My JIRA query currently goes the following:

`(status = "In Progress" OR status="Test Failed") AND assignee = currentUser() order by priority desc, due asc, status desc, key asc`

The problem is, priority is text, and `Medium` comes first before `Low` and `High`. Also if I order my task ascending, `Medium` issues go to the end of the list. I tried the case-when-then expression, but JQL won't let me as they are reserved words. How can I define custom ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Priority is a text field, you get sorting by alphanumerical order (ascii actually I think). Some people work around this by changing the names to 0-High, 1-Medium, 2-Low, or "P1 High", "P2 Medium" and "P3 Low". Or you can define a custom field for Priority as a select field with options named Low, Medium, High and change their order during field configuration.